# Parse query results array returning nill objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to fetch objects from parse however I'm getting a nil array even after the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`.

[image]

[image]

The Question class does exist if you're wondering.
So my question is, why is my array nil even though there are objects in my Question class?

Comment: It's a well stated question, complete with all the evidence of the problem (somewhat unusual for the parse.com tag).  The only other thing I can think of is confirming that the appId, clientKey are correct when you initialize parse.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the issue because Parse worked when I was fetching inside my PFQueryTableViewController.  I wanted to create a Datasource singleton instead.